# Disable spring security for Grails functional tests?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using spring security in my application and have to disable spring security for functional test cases.

so I'm setting the springsecurity.active= false in my config file.

```
 environments {
    doNotCacheCompiledReportTemplates=false
    development {
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = false
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        doNotCacheCompiledReportTemplates=true
    }
    testAutomation {
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = false
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        doNotCacheCompiledReportTemplates = false
        grails.dbconsole.enabled = true
    }
    dev3 {
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = false
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    rubyTest {
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = false
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
}
```

and added print statement in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy

```
println "The Config Activity is: ${conf?.active}"
```

The value is 'True' but expecting 'False' as I had set the property in config.groovy..

Is there anything i'm missing, why the config property is not being read?

Any suggestions around would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be issue with naming of your environments. When running tests you should see logs about selected environment "Environment set to *_*_". In your case it should be "Environment set to testAutomation". To tell grails to run tests in this environment try to run tests with:

`grails -Dgrails.env=testAutomation test-app`

Comment: Thanks Pawel it fix the issue though I've some issues with bean loading for Oauth as Spring security beans are not available now..

Comment: You're welcome. This article may be helpful: http://www.lucasward.net/2011/03/disabling-spring-security-for-grails.html

Answer (score 1):

Tests are run in the test environment, so put the setting in that block.

Comment: But if i put it under env and top of Dev it is working ..like ..environments {
    doNotCacheCompiledReportTemplates=false
     dev{}}

Comment: How you're running your tests?